# May I know if we can integrate json api or odata with ABP 3.x?

Tags: .net-core, odata, json-api, abp

I have one abp 3.1 application and I would like to integrate with json api or odata to have a benefit of "filter" and "fieldset" function during get api.

Example: hosturl/hostname??filter[columnname]=keyword

By default, the get api will response 100 records, but with filter, we can enable search to our preference fields inside the jason response body.

Fieldset is to get only specific column/fields from the json response body. For example, there are 30 fields in response body, but I'll need to get 3 fields on UI.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you had a look at the [.net core tutorial the *How To JSON:API* project](https://howtojsonapi.com/dotnetcore.html)?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there a way to integrate Json API on .netcore boilerplate?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64169081/is-there-a-way-to-integrate-json-api-on-netcore-boilerplate)